# Codeigniter3 giving a 404 after server deployment (Not reading Application Folder)

Tags: php, codeigniter

Seen a couple of questions on this topic, and all seem to be .htaccess related - I've pasted mine below.

.htaccess (stored in the root web folder, above applications):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

CodeIgniter config:

```
$config['base_url']    = 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

SSL Cert installed correctly & tested fine. Also tested with base_url swapped to http, and vhost setup for Port 80. Wildcard cert also tested on a different subdomain without codeigniter, working as expected.

All pages returning with a 404 error. Apache access log shows incorrect endpoints being hit;

Apache error log:

> [core:info] [pid 26683] [client x.x.x.x:53318] AH00128: File does not
>   exist: /var/www/mysite/Account/login

This is the incorrect endpoint - this should be hitting /Application/Account/login to load the Account controller. This is only occurring on the currrent Server setup (Ubuntu 16.04 on a standard LAMP stack).

However, if I were to set up vhosts to start from the Application folder, this would obviously cause me to lose .htaccess, assets, images, etc etc. Would anyone know why CI seems to be looking for controllers under the root directory?

Comment: try to remove index.php from $config['index_page']

Comment: Just to confirm, the root (public) directory of the vhost is /var/www/mysite/ and index.php plus .htaccess are in that folder.

Comment: @EvilsEmpire Tried this, and also tried setting base_url = ''. No difference.

Comment: @DFriend that is correct

Comment: `$config['base_url']` MUST be set. While your problem isn't related to 'index_page', you should set it like this: `$config['index_page'] = '';

Comment: Did you change the CI folder structure in any way?

Comment: @DFriend no. It's standard, with no additional routes set up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171995/discussion-between-dfriend-and-eoghan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you vhost is setup correctly. Typos have major consequences for virtual hosts and the completely wrong location path for the controller might indicate a vhost setup problem.

You can confirm that .htaccess is working, or not, by including index.php in your browser address, e.g.

```
example.com/index.php/account/login
```

If that works but it doesn't when you leave out `index.php` then either `mod_rewrite` is not "on" or your vhost is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

- Check your class name and class file name.
- Class name start with uppercase like "Functions"
- Class file name start lowercase like "functions"
- Controller's name same as class name like "Home_Controller =>
  Home_Controller.php"
- When you include your library in the project, you should write in
  lowercase letters. Like this;

Functions.php => $this->load->library("functions");
$this->functions->yourMethod();